# Trigger Elementor's popup after submitting form (Event after submit) with contact form 7 [Wordpress]

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

I use Elementor popups and contact form 7 at my wordpress website.
What I'm trying to do is to trigger the elementor's popup after the contact form 7 form is submitted.

What I have done so far is bellow. I have no console errors.

My html code:

```
<form>
<input id="popup" onclick="return SubmitForm(this.form)" type="button"  name="elementor-popup-modal-1036"  value="Submit request" />
</form>
```

My js code:

```
document.getElementById("popup").submit= function(){
    elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: 1036 } );

}
function SubmitForm(frm) {
  wpcf7.submit(document.querySelector('.wpcf7-form'));
}
```

Problem is that when I submit my form, popup is not triggered but form is submitted successfully and sent to the recipient. When I use `.onclick` instead of `.submit` in my js it works great and popup is triggered. But what I need to trigger this popup only after submitting the form.

Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Don't you mean `onsubmit`?

Comment: I''ve tried `onsubmit` and `submit` but did not help. Just works when `onclick` is set. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I have figured it out. I have done some research in CF7 documentation and I got that contact form 7 does not support HTML `<form>` elements. So I have done some modifications in my code to open the Elementor's popup after my contact form 7 is submitted and here is the solution.

In contanct form 7 I'm using the classic submit button which is added to your cf7 by default:

```
[submit "Send Mail"]
```

I use js code which checks for event `wpcf7mailsent` ,which is listed after submitting the form and afterwards the elementor popup is triggered by it's ID which you could find in your Elementor's popup shortcode.

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
         elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: 1036 } ); //your Elementor popup ID here
    }
, false );
```

Here is the full code solution. Code goes to your theme's of child theme's functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cf7_elementorpopup' );

function cf7_elementorpopup() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
         elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.showPopup( { id: 1036 } ); //your Elementor popup ID here
    }
, false );
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

Hope that many of you will find this solution helpful in your projects.